# set property to a non-null value of type 'System.Single' error

Tags: c#

In my database data type is Float . in my c# model if i give Decimal i am getting error

My database Table screen shot

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGj1.png
```

Error Message

```
The 'IRR' property on 'DisburseCaseCommissionViewModel' could not be set to a 'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Decimal'.
```

my C# Modal

```
 public class DisburseCaseCommissionViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CaseTFlexId { get; set; }
    public long? WorkRequestId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ContractDate { get; set; }        
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public decimal? CommissionPayoutAmount { get; set; }
    public string CommissionMonth { get; set; }
    public string PayOutType { get; set; }
    public Decimal? IRR { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public long? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public long? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

}
```

If I give double the code is working fine, but double will do round off, I should not do round off.

Comment: Is your Float precision high? If it isn't, double should be okay...

Comment: you can define IRR as float if your database datatype is float.... why should you do mismatch ?

Comment: @DarshanPatel The database type `float` is normally a double-precision floating point.  Single-precision floating point is normally given a different name, like `real`.  They're not the same names that we use in C#.

Comment: You didn't specify your database. Or your mapping library. They both matter a lot.

Comment: if i give float as data type in c# also same error comes

Comment: c# `float` is not the same as SQL `FLOAT` either.

Answer (score 8):

What you've discovered is that you have to match the C# types to the actual data types in the database.  There are various tables out there that match them up, depending on the actual database engine used, so I won't do it here.

Assuming [Microsoft SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) however...

The SQL `FLOAT` data type is a double-precision floating point value equivalent to a `double` in C#.  If you want a `Decimal` then declare it as `DECIMAL()` or `NUMERIC()` in the database structure.

The moral is: setup the database to act how you need it to act, then configure your data layer to talk to it correctly.  If you want to store a `decimal`, make the field a `DECIMAL`.  If you want a `FLOAT` field then use `double` in your code.

Comment: if i am using double its taking round off, for example (2.56) means (3) its coming

Comment: Rounding to integer for a float field should only happen if you are doing something specific to cause it.  Without more information I can't help.